# How Navigation with OnsenUI and react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I try to create prototype Progressive Web APP with React and OnsenUI. One of the characteristics of an PWA is, that the content is linkable. Therefore i want to implement react-router. The OnsenUI provide only a SPA with  or . How do i implement this with the OnsenUI  or  component?